# Where should report generation logic go in a MVC structure?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop

I have a project that uses a Model View Controller setup.

Part of this project is to generate some fairly complex reports that need queries across multiple models.

I currently have a reports controller which handles the request from the user and figures out which report it's supposed to be rendering and with which parameters... unfortunately this controller has also ballooned to include all of the report generation code as well. I'm pretty sure this code doesn't conceptually belong in the reports controller (it's business logic, not routing code) but it also clearly doesn't belong to any specific model.

In terms of good OO design, where should this report generation business-logic type code actually live?

(If it helps make the answer more specific, this is a php project using the CakePHP framework).

Comment: Where did you end up putting your reporting logic? I'm using CakePHP and wondering the same thing. Maybe a component? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider MVC as a core pattern for handling user interaction. It doesn't mean that you should be looking at all the problems your app is trying to solve from MVCs point of view.

If report generation is important part, why not have something like `ReportGenerator` class? Depending on the specifics, it may even be useful to have report generation as a separate process.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer a conceptual answer as well as some practical advice.

Here is the conceptual answer. Think of the computer monitor and the printer as two different machines with the same purpose. Their common task is to display or render text and graphics. Both present a view into the model objects. In the case of the computer monitor, objects are rendered to a screen. In the case of the printer, objects are rendered on a piece of paper.

Conceptually, a report can be rendered either to a screen or to printer. It just a matter of where the information is directed. If it is directed to a monitor, the GUI framework interacts with the OS window manager to create an the view. If the information is directed to a printer, a report generator interacts with the OS and printer driver to create a hard copy.

Such a design might use two hierarchies of view classes, use strategy pattern that plugs into a view class, or the design might be something else entirely. The controller object for the report would be responsible for getting and organizing the data to be rendered.

That is the conceptual answer. In practice, I have never seen it done that way. Every company I have worked with in the last 20 years buys an off-the-shelf report generator package. Then they create a class like **ReportGenerator** in their application and use it as an interface to the commercial reporting software. The reporting software handles the formatting and the loading and saving of report templates. Such software usually includes a nice GUI editor or designing reports. You pass the report generator the name of the report template, the data, and the printer. Then it works its magic to create and print the report.

Sometimes I want to view reports on the screen instead of printing them. In that case, I still use the report generator, but I tell it to create a PDF file of the report. Then I use a Web browser or Adobe Reader to view the report on the screen.

For anything other than a toy project or a prototype, I recommend looking into a software package whose purpose is to generate reports. Seriously.